# I am getting this error- angular.js:14525 TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following error**(angular.js:14525 TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function atChildScope.BindingCode.$scope.Submit (ClientSide.html:36) at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15358), :4:138))** while executing this piece of code. This piece of code is sending the object to the asp.net webapi and after processing is getting the data back-

```
   $scope.Submit = function () {
                    if($scope.Customer.CustomerName.length==0)
                    {
                        alert("Not a proper data");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $http.post("http://localhost:59040/api/Customer", $scope.Customer).
                            success(function (data) {
                            $scope.Customer = data;
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get the same error in the similar solution with angular + asp.net-web-api. The error is related with the version of angular.

The "success" function was deprecated at angular version 1.6.2

In this case the correct sintax

```
   $scope.Submit = function () {
                if($scope.Customer.CustomerName.length==0)
                {
                    alert("Not a proper data");
                }
                else
                {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:59040/api/Customer'
                    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
                        $scope.Customer = data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }
            }
```